# Issues with Firefox and Edge Width

Tags: css, html, web, width

I have a issue with this website: https://purepng.com/ The recommend searches aren't displayed correctly with Firefox and Edge. Chrome is working. There is every time a space.

[image: Recommend Searches with Edge]

Class of the recommend search:

```
.search__tags {
max-width: 715px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
-webkit-padding-start: 0px;}
```

You can find all other .css on the website. I think the issue is the 1% width of the button on the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

What happend if you add this?

```
-moz-padding-start: 0px; padding-start: 0px;
```

Comment: doesn't change anything